# How to define a class within a class for 1 to 1 relationship in xsd

Tags: xsd, jaxb

If I define my xsd schema like below , the xs:element is giving an error. I want to have a 1:1 relationship between BitStatType and ValidationCountMessage?  How can I define a class within a class -- This is for JAXB java.

```
  <xs:complexType name="BitStatType">
                <xs:element name="BitAgeViolation" type="ValidationCountMessage" />                 
                <xs:attribute name="WiId" type="xs:int" use="required"/>
                <xs:attribute name="Title" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
                <xs:attribute name="TriggerRulesCount" type="xs:int" use="required"/>
                <xs:attribute name="TriggerEventsCount" type="xs:int" use="required"/>
                <xs:attribute name="LastPublishedDate" type="xs:date" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you're missing an xs:sequence (just in case, not sure if it got lost in posting or what).

```
<xs:complexType name="BitStatType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="BitAgeViolation" type="ValidationCountMessage"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="WiId" type="xs:int" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="Title" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="TriggerRulesCount" type="xs:int" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="TriggerEventsCount" type="xs:int" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="LastPublishedDate" type="xs:date" use="required"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

If your ValidationCountMessage is a complexType then JAXB should create two classes, one for BitStatType and one for ValidationCountMessage; the BitStatType class will have a field bitAgeViolation, of type ValidationCountMessage. So, you'll have an association between these two classes.